# Determining Weight function in Sturm Liouville problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

By choosing the proper weight function $\sigma (x) $ solve the Sturm-Liouville problem and determine its eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[x\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\right] + \frac{2}{x}y(x) +\lambda \sigma (x)y(x)=0,\; y'(1)=y'(2)=0,\; 1 \leq x \leq 2. $$

I don't understand what it means to "choose" the proper weight function. I tried to rewrite the problem in this form.

$$\frac{1}{\sigma(x)}\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\frac{dy(x)}{dx} + \frac{2}{x}y(x)\right] +\lambda\sigma(x)=0\right], $$

then calculate it by setting  $p(x)=A(x)\sigma (x), p'(x)=B(x)\sigma(x)$ and using this formula:

$$\sigma(x)=e^{\int \frac{A-B'}{B}\,dX}, $$ 
but it doesn't get me anywhere; solving this gives you just $1=1.$

I tried extracting information about the weight function from the boundary condition but i am failing at that too and i tried solving the differential equation using an infinite series but that won't work either because of the unknown weight function. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be a tad easier than you're making it out to be; most of the time, you can simply read off what the weight function should be. See [this link](https://mathhelpboards.com/differential-equations-17/st-rm-liouville-problem-cheat-sheet-16218.html) for a type-up of some notes I got on SL problems, including a downloadable pdf.

For your problem, you need to massage the equation into the right form, from which you can simply read it off:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\right] + \frac{2}{x}y(x) +\lambda \sigma (x)y(x)&=0\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\right] + \frac{2}{x}y(x)&=-\lambda \sigma (x)y(x);
\end{align*}
then you just need a positive weight function. The hope is that some combination of $\sigma(x)$ or $\lambda\sigma(x)$ or $-\lambda\sigma(x)$ or $-\sigma(x)$ is positive.

Alternatively, you could view $1/x$ as the weighting function by writing as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\right]+\lambda \sigma (x)y(x)=- \frac{2}{x}y(x).$$
Depending on how $\sigma(x)$ behaves, this may be the only option, since $1/x$ does not change sign on your interval.

Comment: I don't understand how you determine at the end that $\frac{1}{x}$ can be the weight function because i think the weight function has to be in front of $\lambda$, anyways this might sound weird but the problem states to chose the function, maybe it just isn't possible to determine a specific weight function and what i need to do is just a pick a function that satisfies the SL criteria? If so is $\sigma(x)>0$ the only condition i have to consider? Do i have infinite functions to chose from as long as in the end the eigenfunctions satisfy the boundary conditions?

Comment: No the weight functions have to come from the DE, and they have to be positive and continuous on your interval. As for whether $1/x$ could be the weight function: it depends on your viewpoint. If you want to view $-2$ as the parameter on the right-hand-side, you can do that. The solutions will be orthogonal and complete, because the conditions of the theorem are met.

Comment: If the weight function has to come out from the DE then how can it be determined? Don't you need to know it in order to solve the DE?

Comment: Yes, you do need to know it to solve the DE! But it's part of the original DE and can be read off from the form of the original DE. You do not need to solve the DE in order to find the weight function.

Comment: So i should be able to find one specific expresison of $\sigma(x)$ given the circumstances of this problem? The problem with this is that when i plug different $\sigma(x)$  functions, ( for example $\sigma(x)=1$ and another time $\sigma(x)=x$ ) wolfram still identifies it as SL problem and is still able to find a solution for the DE. If that is true how is there still a way to determine a specific $\sigma$?

Comment: Your comment mystifies me. I now have absolutely no idea exactly what the problem originally is. Could you please edit your question to have the original problem, word-for-word (in English)? Leaving $\sigma$ to find later is a highly unusual kind of problem, not to say impossible.

Comment: The problem is already written this way. Everything after $1\leq x \leq 2$ are my own thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Well, if you're in a class, I would ask your teacher what's meant by this question, because I am unable to help without more information.

Comment: Ok thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

For generic 2nd order (homogeneous) ODE:

$ a(x)y''(x) + b(x)y'(x) +c(x)y(x) = 0 $

To transform it to Sturm Liouville form you need:

$ a(x)>0$ and $a,b,c$ to be on continuous on the interval of definition.

Now the weight function is defined as follows:

$w(x) = \dfrac{1}{a(x)}e^{\int \frac{b(x)}{a(x)}dx}$

We now set:

$ p(x) = w(x)a(x)\\  q(x)=w(x)c(x)$

To do a sanity check find $p'(x)$ which is $b(x)w(x)$

so now you can rewrite the DE to:

$\dfrac{1}{w(x)} \left[ w(x)a(x)y'' + w(x)b(x)y' + w(x)c(x)y \right] =0\\ \dfrac{1}{w(x)} \left[ p(x)y'' + p'(x)y' + q(x) \right] = 0\\ \dfrac{1}{w(x)} \left[ (p(x)y')' + q(x) \right] = 0 $

That's how you reformulate to SL form. Hope this helps and you can work the details for your problem.

Comment: my equation already is in SL form, my problem is that now that its in SL form to choose the proper weight function. I don't understand what it means to choose a proper function... if its already in SL form can't the function be whatever it wants?

Answer (score 0):

Your equation may be written as
$$
                 -xy''-y'+\frac{2}{x}y=\lambda\sigma(x)y \\
                 -x^2y''-xy'+2y=\lambda \sigma(x)xy.
$$
If you are allowed to choose $\sigma(x)$, I would choose $\sigma(x)x=1$. Then you have Euler's equation, which you can explicitly solve:
$$
                         x^2y''+xy'+(2-\lambda)y=0,\;\;\; y'(1)=y'(2)=0.
$$
The solutions where $y'(1)=0$ can be normalized by an added condition such as $y(1)=1$, for example. Then you can solve for $\lambda$ for which $y'(2)=0$, and that determines the eigenvalues $\lambda$.